# Error importing NOAA’s National Geophysical Data Center as delimited text layer in QGIS version 1.02

Tags: qgis, import, delimiter

I've been struggling with trying to import the most recent data from NOAA’s National Geophysical Data Center earthquake information into Quantum GIS 1.02 for weeks now for a class assignment.

I'm attaching three screen shots which show some of what I'm running into.

The first is where I import the information in a delimited text layer.

[image]

The second is the error I continue to run into every time I load the file which I've re-downloaded and attempted to use multiple times with the same error.

[image]

Lastly, is where I'm attempting to make use of the Points in Polygone feature which will load to 100% and then freeze the program.

[image]

Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: looks like the file is in tab delimited format and not comma delimited format. use notepad++ to quickly convert the files.

Comment: Using QGIS 1.0.2 is not recommended. Current Version is 1.8.0, and 2.0.1 will be around soon.